# Arithmetic and Geometric series in one

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, geometric-series

I need to know how to solve this type of problem. Its a practice problem for a math competition:

Given a 4-term sequence such that the first 3 terms form an arithmetic sequence and the last 3 terms form a geometric sequence. If the first term is 2 and the last term is 9, find the third term of this sequence.

Comment: Show please your attempts.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, it is expected that you include your own thoughts on the problem.  Please edit your question to show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the second term and third term be $2+n$ and $2+2n$. Then we make an equation:
$$(2+2n)^2=9(2+n)\\ 4n^2+8n+4=18+9n \\ 4n^2-n-14=0 \\ (4n+7)(n-2)=0 \\ n=-\dfrac{7}{4} \lor n=2$$

So the third term can be $2+2\times-\dfrac{7}{4}=-1.5$ or $2+2\times 2=6$

Comment: Thank you! These answers are correct according to the answer sheet. Just one question though (I'm a beginner to sequences and such) how did you get the equation (2+2n)^2 = 9(2+n)

Comment: As in geometric sequence, the square of a term is the product of the previous term and the next term